# How to write negative numbers in text properly

Tags: hyphenation

I have problems with hyphenation of negative numbers in an `article` document. It sometimes happens that the minus is on one line, whereas the number begins on the next line. A possible fix is to write numbers in math mode, that is with `$` before and after the number. But then the minus becomes very long, which looks odd to me. Compare `$-$` with a simple `-`. I am using `amsmath` and `amsfonts` and `amssymb`, which might be related to that problem. Is there any way to make the minus before numbers shorter?

Comment: But the 'long' minus *is* a minus, whereas the short text mode symbol is a hyphen. Surely math mode is the correct solution.

Comment: @IanThompson So you are saying it must look like this and this is always the case, in let's say most latex packages/frameworks?

Comment: I'm saying that a minus sign should be used to indicate negative numbers, not a hyphen. If the minus sign is too long for your tastes then it should be changed throughout the document, e.g. by using a different font.

Comment: @IanThompson ah okay thanks for the information. Do you happen to know a suitable font?

Comment: What is not used  looks odd, but not necessarily is wrong. Compare  both `-` and `$-$` with the  `$+$` in the same line  ... Which of the two look wrong as mathematical symbol?

Comment: There is a lot of information about fonts at the [LaTeX font catalogue](https://tug.org/FontCatalogue/mathfonts.html). Unfortunately, the examples don't have minus signs in them, so you will need to try some out to see which you prefer.

Comment: Another option would be to use the `\num` macro from the `siunitx` package.

Comment: Thanks everyone!